# Convert RLMResults to RLMArray

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am querying over a RLMArray with objectsWhere and i get a RLMResults, but i need a RLMArray with the results a this point in my code.

```
private var data: RLMArray?

self.data = self.currentSubcategory!.datasheets // is a RLMArray
self.data = self.data!.objectsWhere("is_favourite = 1")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> `RLMArray` has been split into two classes: `RLMArray` and
>   `RLMResults`. `RLMArray` is now used only for to-many properties on
>   `RLMObject` classes, while `RLMResults` is used for all of the
>   querying and sorting methods. This was done to reflect that the two
>   actually had fairly different APIs (for example, `RLMResults` does not
>   have `addObject:`), and they’re expected to diverge further as we add
>   change notifications for queries.
>
> The migration for this should be as simple as replacing `RLMArray`
>   with `RLMResults` in all of the places that the compiler complains
>   about.
>
> To go with this, `arraySortedByProperty:ascending:` has been renamed
>   to `sortedResultsUsingProperty:ascending:`, and `addObjectsFromArray:`
>   has been renamed to `addObjects:` to reflect the fact that you can
>   pass any enumerable object to it (such as `NSArray`, `RLMArray`, or
>   `RLMResults`).

Source: http://realm.io/news/realm-cocoa-0.87.0/#rlmresults

Hope that's enough

Comment: For future Realm newbies like myself, please update this blog post with these changes.  https://realm.io/news/tutorial-building-a-todo-app-with-realm/  Great framework, but documentation is currently a bit fragmented.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add objects from `RLMResult` to `RLMArray`...

```
@implementation RLMResults (RLMArrayConversion)

- (RLMArray *)toArray {
    RLMArray * array = [[RLMArray alloc] initWithObjectClassName:self.objectClassName];
    [array addObjects:self];
    return array;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
let datasheets = self.currentSubcategory!.datasheets!.objectsWhere("is_favourite = 1")
let objects = Array(datasheets.generate())

self.data!.removeAllObjects()
self.data!.addObjects(objects)
```

Creating the array of the results is required because the `self.data!.removeAllObjects()` line will also clear `datasheets`, since `RLMResults` are live-updating as you make changes to the source.